# Exiting the logging from an appender

Tags: log4net, log4net-filter

Is it possible to configure so that log4net stops going through the rest of the appenders if an appender got a match?

Something like:

```
<appender name="TlsReadingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\logs\TPOSIn_TlsReading.log" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
    <loggerToMatch value="TPOSIn.ServiceApp.Tls.TlsHandler"/>
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />

  <dontCheckAnyMoreAppenders />

</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a very long list of appenders but they will only be "Active" if they are referenced in the root tag of your log4net.config file:

```
  <root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileLogAppender" />
  </root>
```

You could create a list of appenders, using "namespace.class" as the name of the appender to filter the events on each file.

Can you share a bit more about your requirements and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I add all in root. But I want to prevent all other appenders from running if one of the first appenders got filters that match.